# How to create a Sub-directory in parent directory using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to create folder in php.I tried this code.It's not creating folder in parent directory.

```
$dir1="http://www.consul.com/hrd/b";
 mkdir($dir1, 0755);
```

Comment: Read [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) before you ask :)

Comment: Please use Google first before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get root directory.
To get root directory

**For PHP >= 5.3.0 try**

```
__DIR__
```

**For PHP < 5.3.0 try**

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

---

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
$dir1 = $root . "/your_folder";
mkdir($dir1, 0755);
```

**EDIT :**  Also can create directory by checking it consistency if required.

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
$dir1 = $root . "/your_folder";
if(!is_dir($dir1)){
   mkdir($dir1, 0755);
}
```

**Reference:**

- [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: I get Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/consul/public_html/hrd/trail2.php

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir()` uses the local directory path, not the server directory path. See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for more info.

You'd want to run the following code:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "hrd/b"; // This gets the server's root directory and creates "hrd/b" relative to it.
mkdir($dir, 0755);
```

Note that for PHP versions < 5.3.0, you'll need to use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dir1="/home/UserName/public_html/DirName";
 mkdir($dir1, 0755);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set $dir1 to a URL instead of providing a path.  Also, if any of the directories don't exist, you may need to use the recursive paramater, as follows:

```
<?php
$dir1 = "/hrd/b";
if (!mkdir($dir1, 0755, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

For more info about this function, you may wish to read http://php.net/mkdir.

I tried this code on a Windows Box using PHP5.4.3, included in WampServer 2.2 (uses Apache 2.2.22) and it worked perfectly.

When I tried the code on a Linux Server running a very early version of PHP5, I had to tweak the path and this is the code that finally worked there:

```
<?php
$dir1 = dirname(__FILE__)."/hrd/b";

if (!mkdir($dir1, 0755, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Note: dirname() and its parameter, a magic constant, together provide the full path of the currently executing PHP script and that info helps in turn to provide the full path info for $dir1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create a directory in the parent dir.

if (!file_exists("../dir_name/")) { mkdir("../dir_name/", 0777, true); }